# sax : trouble with parsing mixed content text

Tags: java, xml, sax

I'm having trouble with a part of a xml file. I'm parsing it with sax and java.
I can't manage to get all the parts of the text (beginning of the text, middle of the text, end of the text).

```
<sometag type="aType">  
     beginning of the text          
     <anothertag type="anotherType" target="aTarget">middle of the text</anothertag>
     end of the text
</sometag>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For us to help you, you're going to have to provide the code that isn't working, otherwise we're just guessing.  Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Everybody messes up implementing the ContentHandler `characters` method, because it's totally unintuitive. The trick is that there can be multiple calls to the characters method for a single element text node, you have to accumulate the passed-in fragments in a buffer.  [See the Java tutorial on SAX.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) With mixed-content you have to get the text from the buffer at startElement and at endElement.

If that doesn't answer your question, show us some code.

Comment: Also, don't think for a minute that you'll only get multiple calls when there's an embedded tag - you'll also **occasionally** get multiple calls seemingly for no reason - I'd guess that they happen on input buffer boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

SAX is often surprising till you know what to expect from experience.

You probably want to temporarily put some console logging in the event handlers, or even just breakpoint them all, and set up a little test to see what you're getting.  I prefer logging in a case like this because it gives me the "big picture" of what I can expect.

FWIW, Stax is a little easier and similar in performance.

Comment: Or, write a standalone utility with a console-logging event handler.  You'll probably use it again.